# How to initialise a vector member variable in the class definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode5, visual-studio-2013, uniform-initialization

The following code compiles OK using XCode 5.0 but not Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <vector>

class VectorInit
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector{1, 2, 3};   // fails to compile using VS 2013
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector{1, 2, 3};

    VectorInit vectorInit;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that Visual Studio reports:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::vector(std::initializer_list<int>,const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'int' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &' c:\visual studio 2013\projects\vector-init\main.cpp 6   1   vector-init
```

I haven't managed to find an example of how to initialise a vector like this in a class definition.

Which compiler is correct?

If the syntax is not valid, is the only option to initialise m_vector in the constructor initialiser list?

Comment: visual 2013 is not yet right with non static member in class initialization in every cases, aggregate fails by only seeing copy constructor for example. initializer_list ctor too.

Comment: @galop1n Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Please can you clarify.

Comment: in class member initialization is a c++11 feature making his debut in VS2013. But when the member is an aggregate, the compiler is buggy and try to use a copy constructor instead. It ignores too constructors taking initializer list and try to match the parameters only with regular constructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In class member initialization is a c++11 feature making his debut in VS2013. But when the member is an aggregate, the compiler is buggy and try to use a copy constructor instead. It ignores constructors taking initializer list too and try to match the parameters only with regular constructors arguments.

A workaround, you can create a temporary vector then move with that syntax until a proper update of the compiler.

```
class VectorInit
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector { std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 5, 7 } };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> How to initialise a vector member variable in the class definition (C++11)

What you are doing is correct. It initializes the data member to have values `1, 2, 3` whenever you instantiate a `VectorInit`.

However, if you needed a different constructor which requires`()`, then you need an alternative syntax:

```
std::vector<int> m_vector = std::vector(5, 42); // five elements set to 42
```

> Which compiler is correct?

The syntax is valid C++, so the non-VS compilers are right.

If your compiler does not support this type of initialization, you could add a constructor to your class as a work-around:

```
class VectorInit
{
public:
  VectorInt() : m_vector{1, 2, 3}{}
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};
```

Comment: Why not private (one vector constructor takes an initializer_list) ?

Comment: @DieterLücking That is another option, although it addresses a different problem (like my second example actually).

Comment: @juanchopanza The VS 2013 compiler won't accept that syntax either.